# Eror in configuring allauth at AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
settings.py

"""
Django settings for classproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '%__uki0du$y1bwf)m!#!(9%k*9$^u%gtbye*283&2mwtj(vh0g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'mainapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'classproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'classproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_cdn')

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend" ,
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend" ,)


SITE_ID = 1

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\class\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\class\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\class\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\class\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\class\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\new_projects\classproject\classproject\settings.py", line 135
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (`enter code here`
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It says AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS: tuple, invalid syntax
please help, thanks in advance.
I removed "..." at Authentication_Backends also still it is not working.
I am using python 3.7.6 version and Django-2.2
Don't understand where the syntax error and why it is saying error.
It says AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS: tuple, invalid syntax
please help, thanks in advance.
I removed "..." at Authentication_Backends also still it is not working.
I am using python 3.7.6 version and Django-2.2
Don't understand where the syntax error and why it is saying error.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.2, [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#authentication-backends) settings must be a `list` of authentication backend (as strings).

You have provided a `tuple` of authentication backend classes. In earlier versions of Django (I think <1.10), [it was a `tuple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#authentication-backends). Starting Django 1.10, this setting (and many other settings) accepts a `list`.

Update `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` value in settings.py as follows:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend" ,
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend" ,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a ']' of **STATICFILES_DIRS**

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `tuple`. First you missed `,]` in your STATICFILES_DIRS

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
 ]
```